# Do Any JS Engines Optimise For Identical Functions With Different Closures?

Tags: javascript, optimization

The following code creates a function named `f`. Each time `f` is invoked, it defines the inner function, then returns it. Each time the inner function is defined and returned, it encloses whatever was passed to `x` for that invocation of `f`.

The array named `a` references multiple instances of the inner function, which are all the same, except that they each enclose a different value for `x`.

```
var f = function(x) {
    return function() { return x };
};
var a = [f(0), f(1), f(2)];
```

Does any JavaScript engine do anything under the hood to allow the multiple instances to be stored in memory as a single function, despite the different closures?

Comment: I'd expect them all to do so. A closure is a function + captured environment. The functions are all the same, only the environment is different.

Comment: [Yes, they do](http://mrale.ph/blog/2012/09/23/grokking-v8-closures-for-fun.html). Though in your case, they don't even enclose `x` in the environments, as you don't access it in the closure, your function are no-ops.

Comment: The inner function references `x` by closure??

Comment: @CarlSmith: But it doesn't do anything with it, so the `x` would be removed by dead-code-elimination.

Comment: Ah, I see, but assuming it did do something with it, the engine would create a single instance of the inner function with multiple environments, one for each closure? +1 for the link by the way.

Comment: I think we should assume he wrote `return x`.

Comment: I did, then edited it out :/ I'll put it back in.

Comment: @CarlSmith: Multiple function objects (they are all distinct from each other), but with shared code.

Comment: This *kind of* looks like trampolining, if you reworked the logic a bit?